# Mesh converted from Text has weird Faces and Directions

Tags: mesh, faces, normals, text-object

So I'm trying to convert text into a mesh with all the normals facing the same direction. I'm getting this weird issue where the convert to function is creating a face at a weird location / direction and I want to get rid of it. Beautifying the mesh helps clean up the mesh but the face facing the wrong direction still exists. I need this to be automated so I can't change it by hand (since I want to extrude the text later after applying some functions to the mesh). Here are some pictures to demonstrate the problem.

Any help or solutions are much appreciated.

Facing Weird Direction Non Beautified :
[image: Facing Weird Direction Non Beautified]

Facing Weird Direction Beautified :
[image: Facing Weird Direction Beautified]

Showing how the face is connected when moved slightly :
[image: Showing how the face is connected when moved slightly]

Comment: It's hard to tell what is happening, first of all if there is something wrong with the _Convert To_ function it is unclear if it is related to the specific Blender version you're using, or it might be related to the font you are using for your text. Have you tried different fonts, do they produce the same weird results? Fonts are basically vector graphics defining the shape of the characters, now there might be vectors which give bad results when converted. @Chris: why would all normals facing in the same direction look weird? A text converted to a mesh usually has all normals facing upwards.

Comment: I'll try with another font, but this is the default blender one so I assumed it would "just work"

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann The changing of the font worked. Would you like to post it as an answer or shall I?